# Select component is ignoring parent onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-select

### Problem:

I have a click event that is part of a parent component behaviour but when selecting the  or  component directly that onClick gets ignored and I haven't been able to figure out why are  events taking precedence.

I have tried several layers of e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() on both the parent and the child but no success.

**This is for a website rendered on mobile**

### This is a simplified version of my issue

```
<div onClick={()=>console.log('Print Something')}>
    <div className='containerStyles' >
        <Select autofocus={false}>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I click on the padding of 'containerStyles' or outside of it the console will print something because the onClick is triggered.

However, if I click on the Select component directly nothing is printed in the console.

### What's needed:

I need some guidance in the priorities of the events and how could I make the console.log print a message when anything inside of it is clicked. Even if the select gets focused I just need to make sure the parent's onClick **also** gets executed.

Comment: I don't get this behavior, for me it works as you'd expect. I don't know if it could have to do with the `autofocus` typo, but I doubt it... You say this is a simplified version. Perhaps the non-simplified version will shed some light.

Comment: I agree. The current code (outside of the typo) should work. Can you reproduce this issue in codesandbox for us to see?

Comment: This is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-dc4pc?fontsize=14) I edited the question too. 

I forgot to mention this is being used on a mobile browser. 

Using the information I got from user9408899 I managed to figure out that for the <Select> on mobile browsers the event used is onTouchEnd not onClick... 

Something must change between the two, I'm thinking onClick calls `stopPropagation()` at some point for mobile? 

the solution for me in the end was to use onTouchEnd() instead of onClick() and somehow that fixed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need some guidance in the priorities of the events

## 1. Vanilla Case

`Click event` will propagate from child to parent, this is the default behavior.

Following examples demonstrate this behavior. Parent's click event will be triggered, even if you click the child element.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="box1" onClick={() => console.log("parent")}>
        <div className="box2" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

---

## 2. stopPropagation (Paddings and Borders)

If you would like to block the default behavior, you need to use `e.stopPropagation` function. I added **padding** and **border** to the child element to illustrate the conditions under which `stopPropagation` works.

Even if you click the borders or paddings, propagation will be blocked by `stopProgation` function.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="box1"
        onClick={e => {
          console.log("parent");
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="box2"
          onClick={e => {
            console.log("child");
            e.stopPropagation();
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 7px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

---

> Even if the select gets focused I just need to make sure the parent's onClick also gets executed.

If `click event` doesn't propagate, make sure `Select` component doesn't have `stopPropagation` function.

Worst case scenario, define a function in the **parent** component and pass it as a **prop** to the child component. Then call this function upon `onClick` event in the **child** component.

Comment: Thanks for the information this is exactly why I wanted to confirm... 

I did try to do a codesandbox and, in there, the elements work, so I'll keep trying to see what other elements in my code are interfering and post an update.

Comment: Using your guidance I managed to figure out the solution that worked for me. 
the event I needed to use was `onTouchEnd` and not `onClick`. I think the <Select> component handles the stopPropagation differently for both... and since my app is for a mobile browser `onTouchEnd` was the one that worked.